# Java swing: How to handle events that occur in subclass

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I want to build a simple calculator and have this simple construction:

```
CalculatorGUI <>----- ButtonPanel <>------ JButton
```

Where Calculator has a JFrame and the ButtonPanel (extends JPanel). The ButtonPanel has JButtons in it.

I want to have a way to pass the JButton events trough ButtonPanel such that I can catch the events in CalculatorGUI. I was thinking about passing events trough ButtonPanel but I do not know how to do such a thing.
Is there another way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why does your ButtonPanel extend JPanel?  You can add JButtons to a JPanel.  Composition is much better than inheritance.  Why do you want to catch the JButton action events in the Calculator GUI?  The point of creating a ButtonPanel class is that you handle everything related to JButtons in the ButtonPanel class.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: I think that he's showing a composition relationship in his [UML diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram). Those aren't arrows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an interface to make that happen.  Create that interface in your button panel and implement that interfaceListener in your calculator GUI. Declare your method names in interface your calculator GUI will have to override them.  Then in your  button's event use that interface to let the GUI know about it